# Order of HttpInterceptors

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-httpclient

I have a application that uses a plugin that register a HttpInterceptor.

Now I need to create my own interceptor that need to be run **before** the other interceptor because it will change some values, in localStorage, that the other interceptor uses.

How can I influence in the execution order when registering a new HttpInterceptor?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#interceptor-order

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot set interceptors order. Interceptors are chained in order they are declared.

You will have write your own super interceptor that will allow to append child interceptors with some ordering logic.

Comment: So what you're saying is that you can set interceptors order by declaring them in a specific order.

Comment: caso um dos interceptors esteja em um modulo e outro nao como fica essa ordem

Comment: Please delete your answer, this is not true.

Answer (score 21):

https://angular.io/guide/http-intercept-requests-and-responses#interceptor-order

> Angular applies interceptors in the order that you provide them. If you provide interceptors A, then B, then C, requests flow in A->B->C and responses flow out C->B->A.